# Hide a branch in Mercurial / TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, branch, tortoisehg

We are planning on having named branches for client releases of from a core version of our product.

We do not wish to clutter TortoiseHg's branch diagram with unrelated branches i.e. the diagram is going to get massive as we add more and more client's.

Is there a way to hide everything else other than the locally current branch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think that there is a way to do it automatically, but you can filter the TortoiseHg graph on a lot of criteria and by named branch is one of the options.

On the `Revision Details` task page you can click on the filter icon (the one that is a magnifying glass).  This brings up an extra toolbar above the revision graph with various filter options.  The one on the far right is a drop down that says `* Show All *` by default.  Click that and select the branch that you want to see.  You can close this toolbar and the filter will remain applied (the repository tab indicates this by having the filtered branch in the tab)

Answer (score 25):

1. View → Filter toolbar (Ctrl-S)
2. In the box, enter something like this:

   `branch(default) or branch("branch 1") or branch("branch 2")`
3. Press Enter

Now only the branches `default`, `branch 1` and `branch 2` are visible, all others are hidden.

You can close the filter toolbar again without affecting the current filter. The background will stay yellow to alert you that there is an active filter.

If you uncheck the box "filter" it will show all changesets again, but those not matching the curent filter will be greyed out.

To create more advanced filters you can press the small ellipsis (…) to open a query wizard.

Comment: Using the revset expression/filter is *much* more useful than showing a single branch (which is only practical in the most trivial cases). The serach can use the [full revset support](https://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets), such as `ancestors` to also include other branches that worked their way in to the branches (or revisions) of interest.

Answer (score 3):

You have at least two choices:

1. Clone to special repo single branch, work around this repo and pull|push to big repo with customer branches on request
2. TortoiseHG - `Global Settings` - `<Repo> settings` (or from workbench: Select repo - `File` - `Settings`) - `Workbench` - `Dead Branches`.

Define all "must be hidden in workbench" branches here

[image: Dead Branches]

Comment: Option (2) does not hide them in workbench from the graph/history view, only from the branches dropdown list. By default, closed branches are not shown there.